# Git: list tags and date/time for all commits in a branch

Tags: git, python-2.7, git-plumbing

For my Python project, i need to fetch data from a git repository.

At the moment i'm using:

```
git rev-list --pretty [branch]
```

to list all commits in the branch with date, time and commit message.

But since the repository i'm working with relies on tagging, i need to read the tags for each commit as well.

This git log command shows me the tags, but for all branches plus i cant use it in my script, since its a porcelain command.

```
git log --tags --decorate
```

Does Anybody know a command i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify pretty formats to rev-list too,

```
git rev-list --first-parent --pretty=%d $branch
```

or to match your current,

```
format=Author:%x09%an
format+=%x0aDate:%x09%ad
format+=%x0aRefs:%x09%d
format+=%x0a%x0a'%w(,4)%s'
format+=%x0a%x0a'%w(,4,4)%b'

git rev-list --pretty="$format" $branch
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what i was looking for!